# Is there a more efficient way to generate a frequency column in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency, data-cleaning

I am running KNN across a dataset that includes some classifiers which I would like to convert into a numeric value based on the probability that two columns are what they are.

Is there a more efficient way to measure the probability that column A is seen in respect to Column B and include it as a new column within the data frame?

When attempting to run as.data.frame(prop.table.... I get the error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 4.0 Gb

My current approach is:

```
df <- read.table(text="
Animal  Colour  Age
Cat Black 3
Cat White 14
Cat Black 5
Cat Black 2
Cat Brown 7
Dog Black 3
Dog Brown 3
Dog Brown 2
Mouse White 1
Rabbit White  4
Rabbit Black  2
Rabbit Brown  3",
header=T)

ptdf <- as.data.frame(prop.table(table(df$Animal, df$Colour), 1))

df$AnimalColourFrequency = subset(ptdf, Var1==df$Animal & Var2==df$Colour)$Freq
```

For reference: Column A has over 9000 unique values, Column B has around 34K values, the dataset has 8.5 million rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, .N, .(Animal, Colour)][, Freq := prop.table(N), Animal][]

#   Animal Colour N      Freq
#1:    Cat  Black 3 0.6000000
#2:    Cat  White 1 0.2000000
#3:    Cat  Brown 1 0.2000000
#4:    Dog  Black 1 0.3333333
#5:    Dog  Brown 2 0.6666667
#6:  Mouse  White 1 1.0000000
#7: Rabbit  White 1 0.3333333
#8: Rabbit  Black 1 0.3333333
#9: Rabbit  Brown 1 0.3333333
```

Comment: That computed much faster without any memory errors. Thanks.   

How would I go about appending that frequency value to the original data table as a new column?

Comment: For future reference, this article has some good reasons why to use data.table instead of data.frame: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/05/data-table-data-frame-work-large-data-sets/

And I currently have 41 tabs open in Chrome stealing my resources...

Comment: You could left join the output from above to `df`. So if your save the above output in `df1`, you could do `df[df1, on = c('Animal', 'Colour')]`

Answer (score 0):

Try the dplyr way for more efficiency:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  count(Animal, Colour) %>% 
  group_by(Animal) %>% 
  mutate(prop=n / sum(n))
# Animal Colour     n  prop
# <chr>  <chr>  <int> <dbl>
#   1 Cat    Black      3 0.6  
# 2 Cat    Brown      1 0.2  
# 3 Cat    White      1 0.2  
# 4 Dog    Black      1 0.333
# 5 Dog    Brown      2 0.667
# 6 Mouse  White      1 1    
# 7 Rabbit Black      1 0.333
# 8 Rabbit Brown      1 0.333
# 9 Rabbit White      1 0.333

df %>% inner_join(df2)
```

If this does not work, there's also data.table